# Need help with RegisterWindowMessage and SendMessage from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have this code in C#:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpProcName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
   IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

and I need to convert this from C++ to C#:

```
UINT UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS = ::RegisterWindowMessage(_T("BT_UARTCTRL_TRANSFER"));
::SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS, 0, 0);
```

and this:

```
UINT UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS = ::RegisterWindowMessage(_T("BT_UARTCTRL_TRANSFER"));
::SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS, 1, 0);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question? "Can you do it for me?"

Answer (score 4):

Should be pretty straight forward.  You'll need to change the PInvoke definitions to `public` inside the class that contains them:

```
public class Win32Api
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
      IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Then for the calls, they would look like this:

```
uint UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS = Win32Api.RegisterWindowMessage("BT_UARTCTRL_TRANSFER");
Win32Api.SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
```

and this:

```
uint UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS = Win32Api.RegisterWindowMessage("BT_UARTCTRL_TRANSFER");
Win32Api.SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);
```

Comment: (IntPtr)1 and IntPtr.Zero required.

Comment: thanks for the help, i got error the name 'HWND_BROADCAST' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = (IntPtr)0xffff`. Nobody is going to define these values for yourself. You have to do it. Google will fill in the missing values.

Comment: Thanks for updating this for me, just got back.